# Why this solution taken from SOF not take effect?

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a `JTextField` accept only number. And I found solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996430/input-text-only-accepts-numbers/21996565#21996565).

```
    ((AbstractDocument)textField_time.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
            fb.insertString(offset, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), a);
        }

    });
```

Above is my code, and alphabet can still be typed in;

Comment: It looks like you forgot to finish writing your question?

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi Might because that you ignored title:)

Comment: @bijiDango no, it is because your question is incomplete; and ends with a semicolon.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11093326/230513).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to override the `replace(...)` method of the `DocumentFilter`. This is the method that gets invoked by the Swing text components as you enter text via the GUI.

The `insertString(...)` method is only invoked when update the Document directly by using:

```
Document doc = textField_time.getDocument();
doc.insertString(...);
```

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for a complete implementation. You can even turn the "debug" variable on to verify that the replace() method is invoked.